# Как запустить свое веб-приложение на Jetty в IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, jetty

Здравствуйте!
Я разрабатываю Spring MVC веб-приложение и мне нужно чтобы оно работало на Jetty-сервере, не требующем внешнего контейнера.
Я добавил сервер jetty стандартным образом через "edit run configuration".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он также успешно отображается в Project Structure.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, когда я запускаю Jetty то он просто не запускается и выдает мне следущее:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java" -DSTOP.PORT=0 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -DOPTIONS=jmx -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -classpath "D:\jetty-distribution-9.3.7.v20160115\start.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\lib\tools.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main --module=jmx C:\Windows\Temp\context4config\jetty-contexts.xml
[2016-03-03 07:17:55,511] Artifact DVDExchange:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Detected server http port: 8080
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Windows\Temp\context4config\jetty-contexts.xml
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:90)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsLinkSupport.getRealPath(WindowsLinkSupport.java:259)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(WindowsPath.java:836)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(WindowsPath.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.FS.toRealPath(FS.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.StartArgs.addUniqueXmlFile(StartArgs.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.StartArgs.resolveExtraXmls(StartArgs.java:1123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information
Disconnected from server

Process finished with exit code -9
```

Возможно, одна из причин - это пустой файл jetty-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

</Configure>
```

Как мне все-таки застваить Jetty работать?
Приведите пожалуйста весь список файлов что нужно описать, а еще лучше поделитесь живым примером (туториалом или исходником), где четко все описано что и зачем. Мне очень срочно нужно разобраться с этим jetty.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите Application server > Configure

Comment: @Владимир Если это xml файл такой, то у меня его нет в проекте. Есть только ApplicationContext.xml, DispatcherServlet и Web.xml

Comment: Вот если что - я обновил вопрос и вложил скрин с конфигурацией сервера приложения

Comment: Кто-нибудь знает ответ?

Comment: Вот аналогично: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654476/how-can-i-start-jetty-from-intellij-on-windows

Comment: Я так и делаю - это показано на скриншотах. Но вылетает ошибка, что деплой недоступен, коннекта нет. Ошибка выше приведена - в вопросе.

Comment: Создайте пустое web приложение. File > New > Project > Java > JavaEE > WebAplication. Больше ничего не делаем. Настраиваем Jetty и запускаем. Пишем ошибку, если падает.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали. Создал пустое WebAplication из раздела JavaEE. По умолчанию в качестве сервера в нем уже стоял натстроенный Jetty. При запуске выдал ровно ту же ошибку. Напишу в следующем сообщении ибо большая.

Comment: com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main --module=jmx C:\Windows\Temp\context0config\jetty-contexts.xml
[2016-03-03 02:45:51,340] Artifact JettyTest:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Detected server http port: 8080
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:

Comment: В общем та же ошибка

Comment: Кстати пустой Web Application на томкате хорошо запускается, а потом при установке всяких навесов в виде фреймворков спринг и hibernate перестает запускать приложение и даже если пройти по его адресу с портом в браузере, то будет лишь белая страница

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отвечаю на собственный вопрос, дабы поделиться со всеми опытом.
Не во всех уроках есть информация о том, что нужно нажать галочку на **Use custom context root**:

[image: run/debug configurations for jetty]

**Без этой галочки сервер и не запускался**, хотя Intellij IDEA пропускала такую конфигурацию и не требовала, чтобы эта галочка была отмечена, т.е. спокойно можно было нажать Apply и без нее. В поле рядом с этим checkbox через слэш пишите что угодно, что хотите, чтобы отображалось в адресной строке браузера после **localhost:8080**. И вуаля - все работает.

Также проверьте настройки версии языка в IDEA и конкретно в проекте - они должны удовлетворять требованиям вашей текущей версии сервера Jetty.

Надеюсь вам это тоже поможет если у вас возникла подобная ситуация.

Comment: К сожалению это не работает при развёртывании EAR приложения в GlassFish:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525485/use-custom-context-root-does-not-work-for-deployment-ear-application-to-glassf